# Javascript - Select H1 inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, qtip2

I've searched all I can about this and found answers that are seemingly correct. But it doesn't work for me. I have this CKEditor inside a div. Inside this CKEditor, there are lots of content and I want to add a hover event on all H1 styles inside this editor.

The div structure looks like this:

```
<div id="content" class="cke_editable">
   <h1>
      <span>My content</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use qTip2 actually, since it seems to fit my needs. But I can't manage to select the H1 tag. Is it because it's inside a div which has both an ID and a class? Or does it have anything to do with the fact that there's a `<span>` tag inside the H1?

Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shared = {
    position: {
        my: 'top left', 
        at: 'bottom right',
    },
    style: {
        tip: true
    }
};

$('h1').qtip( $.extend({}, shared, { 
    content: 'An example tooltip',
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-red'
    }
}));
</script>
```

When it comes to the selector, I've tried selecting only H1, like in this example. As well as `$('.cke_editable h1')`, `$('#content h1')` and `$('#content > h1')`. But no dice. In my CSS, I've successfully added `cursor: pointer` to `#content h1`. And that works.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: If I select `$('#content').qtip` directly, it works btw.

Comment: Does CKEditor even create those elements? I thought it was just a textarea with html in it.

Comment: What do you mean? CKEditor creates H1 elements if I select the Heading style. CKEditor is applied to all divs with the `cke_editable` class set. As well as `contenteditable="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CKEditor creates an iframe where it puts the content, so you can't use a jQuery selector to select the element inside it, as it's not even in the same document any more.

Comment: Aha! I googled that, and it seems you're right!
`var frameDOM = $('iframe.ckeditor').contents(); 
$('.selector', frameDOM).qtip()`

Comment: I can't get anything from frameDOM like this. In Chrome, I see that Object in frameDOM is empty.

Comment: @KennyBones: With the current implementation it looks like you should use `var frameDOM = $('iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents();`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it like this:

```
$('h1','#content').qtip
```

or:

```
$('#content').find('h1').qtip
```

Comment: No dice there as well! I think it's strange. Perhaps it's the CKEditor that messing with it? I tried selecting `$('.cke_editable')` as well, and that didn't work either. Could it have anything to do with the order the scripts are loaded?

Comment: Seems like other people have the same issue: http://ho.runcode.us/q/howto-apply-a-jquery-plugin-qtip-inside-ckeditor

Comment: It's in doc ready. But I think Guffa is on to something. It's not in the same DOM anymore once the content is loaded in CKEditor